# What causes the "operation took too long" error during integration in Perforce?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I have a branch that contains roughly 10000 files. There are not too many changes, roughly 50 of them are affected.

Sometimes integration goes fine, and the changelist is ready in several seconds. On other cases, the integration consistently times out (cannot merge the files in 180 seconds). It cannot be a temporary load spike.

The only workaround I know is that I integrate the stuff in smaller chunks, sometimes even the integration of the subfolders timeouts.

It seems it happens when the two branches are not directly related (one is not a direct branch of the other, but files have a common ancestor somewhere). But the time to complete the operation is still disproportionate (seconds vs minutes).

What causes these timeouts, and how can I mitigate it?

Comment: What message, exactly, do you get?

Comment: @BryanPendleton 

"Operation took too long (over 180 seconds); see 'p4 help maxlocktime'."

I don't have admin privileges to set it higher...

Comment: Your command may be encountering the MaxLockTime limit due to the activity of other users on the server. In which case, you can't do much to your command to improve the situation, because the problem is not caused by your command, but by other commands that are blocking you.